# Get Context from a non activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, alert, android-context, android-toast

Is it possible to get a Context from a non activity class?
Without making a method in the activity class to get the activity?

Maybe with a new Thread or starting a new invisible Activity to show the Toast and then go back to the Activity before.

My Idea is to write a package with some methods to show messages via Toast or Alert. That I only have to import the package and can show a Toast for example.

**Edit:
Maybe I should say that I will use the package for my App which uses a Service in Background and if I close the App the App runs on in background and crashes when I call a Toast. The error is a Nullpointer Exception, which I get from the Alert only if I closed the App and the Service is restarting in Background.**

**Edit:
Code:
This is the Method from the Service. Services is the classname and this is starting automatically if I close the app the service is starting again.**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mT(Services.this,"Service starting");
    A.mA(MyActivity.getAct(),"Title", "Message", R.drawable.ninja,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mT(Services.this, "Clicked");
                }
            }
            );
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**And the Alert and the Toast will be displayed by Starting the Service, but not if I close the App and the service is starting again in Background. The funny Thing is that the Toast will be displayed if I delete the alert but not the alert. The error message is:**

```
08-19 18:37:30.479    4591-4591/productions.ingos.gpstracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service productions.ingos.gpstracker.Services@417322e8 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2553)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:359)
        at ingos.productions.DP.mA(DP.java:29)
        at productions.ingos.gpstracker.Services.onStartCommand(Services.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2536)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**The methods for the Alert and the Toast are in the class DP:**

```
 public static void mT(Context ct,String str)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ct,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

 public static void mA(Context ct,String title, String message,Integer icon,DialogInterface.OnClickListener Dif)
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ct).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", Dif);
        alertDialog.setIcon(icon);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: You can pass in context like the current Toast method does.  makeText (Context context, string value, int duration). You can also pass it Context to your class when you initialize it.

Comment: Can you please post some code and your log cat message

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in context like the current Toast method does. makeText (Context context, string value, int duration). You can also pass it Context to your class when you initialize it.

[Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) uses a public static method if you go that route

Answer (score 0):

If your class is fragment then simply getActivity() method will give you the context if a simple java class then you need to create constructer in that class with an argument of Context  which can get context from the Activity that initializes it.